# Connect to Snowflake using odbc in c#

Tags: odbc

I am trying to connect to Snowflake using odbc connection. I have created a user DSN in odbc data source administrator on windows. When I am trying to connect through odbc in c#, its giving me an error that data source name not found and no default driver specified. Can anyone give me an example of connection string needed for same and how I could fix this error. I am using Visual Studio for development.

Comment: The C# app may not be running under the user account you expect. Try creating a System DSN instead of a User DSN. The next-most-likely issue is a bitness mismatch between layers of your connection; [this article](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/MsSqlOn64bitWin) may help you dig into that.

Comment: I installed the 32 bit odbc snowflake driver and set up dsn for that. It worked! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio IDE is 32-bit.

The original User DSN was set up with a 64-bit ODBC driver for Snowflake.

The solution was to install and set up a DSN with a 32-bit ODBC driver for Snowflake.